# How to use my native script (Tamil) in textbox wpf controls

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I'd like to use my native language script (Tamil). I've decided to use the windows default font Latha, which was designed especially for Tamil. However I couldn't type the native language in the text box. when i was typing it was capturing English only. How to achieve this ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: I am not 100% sure the issue is only related to WPF. if you open word pad and select the font you want to use, are you able to type Tamil characters with your keyboard?

Comment: I tried with Word but i couldn't type Tamil font. so i think i should drill more on this.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried with adding custom font family resource like this ?

```
<FontFamily x:Key="MyFontFamily">/Fonts/FontName__.TTF</FontFamily>
```

and you can use this `Style` to your `TextBox FontFamily`.

Comment: got any solution to your problem ?

Comment: @Smaug Hai,Have you tried the way I answered ? resolved?